# while dispatching incoming RPC call in gwt

Tags: gwt, rpc

I have RPC call to get some values from Database, I using GWT, where am using RPC call, the same code works fine with IE, but the same code doesn't work with Firefox. This does not make sense.

```
2011-07-28 15:27:47.657:WARN:/:Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
java.lang.SecurityException: Blocked request without GWT permutation header (XSRF attack?)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.checkPermutationStrongName(RemoteServiceServlet.java:272)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:203)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Comment: I think you will need to actually pose a question and expand your submission with at least some context before you can get an useful answer.

Comment: Really sorry for this, Acutally i have RPC call to get some values from Database, I using GWT, where am using RPC call, the same code works fine with Internet explorer, but the same code doesn't work with Firefox, could you please help here.

Answer (score 3):

In GWT 2.3 cros-site request forgery was added, I assume you have already looked at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf.html and made the necessary changes?

Comment: Thanks for your response, by overridden the below method it worked, /**
    * It will check PermutationStrong name only when it is set.
    * Content-Type text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8 ... this is temporary solution.
    * X-GWT-Permutation F1AEC601C5D8E4490E7096AB58EB
    */ 
    @Override
   protected void checkPermutationStrongName() throws SecurityException { 
      final HttpServletRequest req = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
      if (!req.getContentType().contains("text/x-gwt-rpc")) {
         super.checkPermutationStrongName();
      }
   }